# Is it possible to see a ping from a LAN computer to an unknown destination?

Tags: router, dhcp, ping, privacy, data-integrity

rookie question...

Two computers in a home network connected only by Ethernet to a router. The router is connected to internet and gives the computer ip:s like 192.168.10.xx. One of the computers makes a simple PING request to something external, like "ping google.com" Is it possible for the other computer to see this? To see what destination is being pinged? Let's broaden the question: Is it possible for one computer to see ANY other traffic the other computer is having with stuff on the web?

I firstly wants to know Yes/No and secondly, "how"

Thanks

Comment: What degree of manipulation do you allow? Can you change settings on the computer that should be sniffed? Can you modify the router?

Answer (score 1):

In common a LAN router's part is a switch, not a hub. To ping any external address 1st PC sends the packet to its own default gate, i.e. router's LAN address. So this packet will not be trasnsmitted to a port which PC2 is connected in. So no way for PC2 to detect that PC1 pings some external address at all - no source data for it.

Answer (score 0):

If the remote computer is configured to respond to ICMP packets then abdolutely. Most computers have this enabled by default. But i misread the question. Yes it is possible but what you are talkong about doing is considered a man in the middle attack. I would advise against it unless you are the owner of said remote pc.

Comment: thanks for answer. Of course I am owner of all computers in my network. I don't understand how it would be possible though? Neither computer have access to the router in any way other than "getting internet" from it

Comment: Shouldn't this totally depend on what router they are connected to? Some routers has vulnerabilities and some don't, right?

Answer (score 0):

With your current hardware setup, it is highly unlikely. If you had a separate switch between the hosts and the router, you might be able to do it; it would depend on if the switch had port spanning capabilities.  If you had a hub between the hosts and the router you absolutely could do it (that's exactly the purpose of a hub - to send all packets to all ports) - all you'd need is a way to capture them (such as Wireshark).